# OpenPyXL doesn't save to new Excel file with replaced changes

Tags: python-3.x, excel, replace, save, openpyxl

I'm trying to replace values in an Excel file (OCR with Tesseract is causing incorrect characters)
It's writing the new Excel file fine, but it's not using the replaced values.

Edit - forgot a .value. This works.

```
import openpyxl
import re

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file01.xlsx')
# print(wb.sheetnames)
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
number_rows = ws.max_row

# Set Column number here ! Column 8 is H.

for rownum in range(1, number_rows):
    try:
        currentcell = ws.cell(row=rownum, column=8).value
        # print("Original", currentcell)
        # replace anything that's not € or a digit . or , (OCR errors)
        ws.cell(row=rownum, column=8).value  = re.sub(r"[^€$\d\.\,]", "", currentcell)
        # print("Replaced with value: ", currentcell)
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")

wb.save(r'F:\PathToFile\fixed01.xlsx')
```

You can test this with an Excel file file01.xlsx with in column H:

```
€105,00|
€90,00)
€200,00)
€30,00)
€60,00)
€60,00)
€60,00}
€60,00)
€20,00)
€63,00)
€25,00)
€25,00|
€63,00)
€25,00|
```

is

```
currentcell = re.sub(r"[^€$\d\.\,]", "", currentcell)
```

not overwriting the current value of that cell??

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.cell(row=rownum, column=8).value = re.sub(r"[^€$\d\.\,]", "", currentcell)
```

Works (forgot a .value)